# How to Create ID3D12VideoDevice correctly?

Tags: c++, microsoft-graph-api, directx-12

Microsoft Docs doesn't give the example, I try to obtained from ID3D12Device, But Failed: https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/7c5tKm9YZH/

Answer (score 4):

You obtain the `ID3D12VideoDevice` interface from your `ID3D12Device` instance.

```
HRESULT hr = pD3D12Device->QueryInterface(IID_PPV_ARGS((void**)&pD3D12VideoDevice));
if (FAILED(hr))
{
    // Driver or Windows doesn't support DirectX 12 Video.
}
```

or if you are using the [Microsoft::WRL::ComPtr](https://github.com/Microsoft/DirectXTK/wiki/ComPtr) smart-pointer:

```
using Microsoft::WRL::ComPtr;


ComPtr<ID3D12Device> pDevice;

// Create the Direct3D 12 device using D3D12CreateDevice


ComPtr<ID3D12DeviceVideo> pVideoDevice;
HRESULT hr = pDevice->As(&pVideoDevice);
if (FAILED(hr))
{
    // Driver or Windows doesn't support DirectX 12 Video.
}
```

For details on creating as `ID3D12Device`, see [this blog post](https://walbourn.github.io/anatomy-of-direct3d-12-create-device/).

Comment: However,  following your answer,  why ID3D12VideoDevice is NULL ?https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/7c5tKm9YZH/

Comment: What HRESULT did you get back from ``As``?

Comment: E_NOINTERFACE No such interface supported. @Chuck Walbourn

Comment: Then your driver doesn't support DirectX 12 video.